# Understanding why $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1+\cos^2x} \geq \frac{\pi}{4}\bigl( 1 + \sqrt{2}\bigr)$

Tags: integration, inequality, elliptic-integrals

Lately I stumbled accros the magnifient paper by Roger Nelsen,
which can be found here [Symmetry and Integration](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/CMJ/Nelsen39-41.pdf)
In this paper it is shown that 
$$  
  \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + \tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}
$$
Takes up exactly half of the area of the rectangle with base $\pi/2$
and height $1$. This idea is supported geometrically by a very convincing figure.
The argument was also done mathematically by noting that if 
$$ f(x) + f(a+b-x)$$
happens to be a constant, then one can proceed as above.

I wanted to find an counter intuitive example where it would be misleading to look at the figure. The integral I found was an elliptic one, namely
$$
   A = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x} \mathrm{d}x \approx 1.9100
$$
Which when drawn looks something like

- [image: The figure of cosine]

The image is very suggestive into thinking that the area of the figure should be
$$
  \tilde{A} = \frac{\pi}{4}\bigl( 1 + \sqrt{2}\bigr) \approx 1.8961
$$
Where only the formula for the trapezoid was used. This idea is wrong since clearly
$1.9100 > 1.8961$. Mathematically one can argue by looking at $f(x) + f(a+b-x)$ one sees that
$$
 f(x) + f(\pi/2-x) = \sqrt{1+\cos^2x} + \sqrt{1+\sin^2x}
$$
it is not constant. The function wobbles very slightly between $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{6}$. This proves that the function $\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}$
does not have the symmetric properties one thought it had.

Using the same argument on $\sin^2x$ or $\cos^2x$ on $\pi/2$ 
shows that $f(x)+f(\pi/2-x)=1$, and hence the function "fills"
exacly half of the square with base $\pi/2$ and height $1$.

My question about this problem is two fold:

1. What is it in the elliptic function that breaks the symmetry?
   Clearly it is not the trigonometric part.
2. Why is the integral *bigger* than the "expected" value?

I can use Romberg, Trapezoid or any numerical integration method to evaluate the elliptic integral. But I still do not see intuitively why the area is bigger, nor what breaks the nice symmetry.

Comment: Nothing exact, but near $0$, you have $$\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x} \approx \sqrt{2(1-\frac{x^2}{2})} \approx \sqrt{2} - \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$ Near $\pi/2$, you have $$\sqrt{1 + \cos^2 (\pi/2-\delta)} \approx \sqrt{1+\delta^2} \approx 1 + \frac{\delta^2}{2}.$$ So the decay near $0$ is approximately by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ slower than the growth near $\pi/2$.

Comment: $1+cos^2$ is a symmetric function on the interval, while the square-root is not. That is why the composition is not symmetric.

Comment: Is a composition of symmetric functions always symmetric? Are there any relevant material references to symmetry and functions? I am not very versed in this matter, as you can probably tell =)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(\pi/4)(1+\sqrt{2}) \approx 1.896$ in the title? [rather than twice that or $3.79$ which is too large]

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+u}$ to the fourth term is
$$t(u)=1+\frac{u}{2}-\frac{u^2}{8}+\frac{u^3}{16}-\frac{5u^4}{128}.$$
For $u \le 1$ the full taylor series is, from the second term onwards, alternating in sign and with strictly decreasing absolute values: If $a_n$ is the absolute value of the coefficient of $u^n$ then (for $n\ge 1$) we have $a_{n+1}=\frac{2n-1}{2n+2}\cdot a_n.$
It follows that, if we substitute $u=\cos^2 x$ into $t(u),$ we have $\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}\ge t(\cos^2 x).$ The latter contains even powers of cosine, and can be integrated explicitly from $0$ to $\pi/2$. The result is 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} t(\cos^2 x) dx=\frac{19857\pi}{32768}=1.9037..$$
Note that this exceeds $\pi/4 (1+\sqrt{2})=1.896..$ and is a bit less than the value $1.910098..$ of the integral of $\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}.$